# Displaying a list in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I have the following list component:

```
import ListItem from './ListItem';
import React from 'react';
import { ListView, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var sampleList = {"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"};

        return ( <ListView data={sampleList} renderRow={
            ({item}) => <ListItem element={item}/>
          }
        />);
    }
}
```

Where `ListItem` is:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>{this.props.element.value}</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

For that, on the emulator I'm getting:

```
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'dataSource.rowIdentities')
```

Any idea what is wrong with this list?

Comment: Looking at [the `ListView` docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html), I *do* see that it's deprecated and I *don't* see that it accepts a `data` property... Moreover, I would expect that if it did, it would expect an array or other iterable rather than a non-iterable object.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` component expects an array as a `dataSource` prop so your initial data for the `ListView` is not correct. Another thing is `ListView` component is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html). You should use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) or [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) components. You can use something like below.

```
render() {
  var sampleList = [
    {item: "A"},
    {item: "B"},
    {item: "C"}
  ];
   return ( <FlatList data={sampleList} renderItem={
            ({item}) => <ListItem element={item}/>
          }
        />);
    }
```

And in your ListItem component you can read your value like below

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>{this.props.element}</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to pass a JavaScript dictionary though as an argument. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: You can modify your dictionary with [Object.keys(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and create a new array as a data for the List.

Comment: @octavian another think I should noticed now is that ListView expects a dataSource and not a data prop. You really should consider using FlatList. I updated my answer

Comment: hi @bennygenel, i tried using FlatList but the renderItem() renders each time per object in the array, could you please take a look?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times
Thank you