# React Native FlatList - Re-Renders / Mounts child items more than once

Tags: javascript, react-native

https://snack.expo.io/SykFiqQ8E

I've been coding a react-native app that utilizes FlatList (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist). I noticed some performance issues with the child items in the list, where the FlatList component will re-render/mount the child items more than once if I add more data to the dataset. That fact is not visible to a user but in the stack trace I am able to prove it renders that child item more than once by just doing an Alert each time it renders.

See the snack for a live demo of the issue and just click add item. It will alert the child items more than once per item. I can't tell if my implementation is wrong or if I need to create an issue on react native's github.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [{key: 'i love rn but why do my items render/mount more than once'}]
  }

  addItem() {
    const data = this.state.data.concat({key: "item#" + this.state.data.length.toString()})
    this.setState({ data })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key} {Alert.alert(item.key)}</Text>}
        />
        <Button onPress={this.addItem.bind(this)} title="Add Item" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

I'm not sure how fast they'd respond so was looking to get some feedback here.

Comment: Check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. reading the comments on both led me to resolving it here: https://snack.expo.io/B1KoX-EUN - I confirmed you can use shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) to diff this.state or this.props and return true/false - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate docs say this callback should be used only for optimization which is what we're doing here.